# variable name cannot be resolved but I have already created the variable

Tags: java, javax.imageio

```
try {
    try {
        Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("target.png"));
        String imgpath = "target.png";
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();}
    } finally {
        int width = img.getWidth();
        int height = img.getHeight();
    }
}
```

I have already created "img" in this line:

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("target.png"));
```

But when I want to get the dimensions of "img" in these lines;

```
int width = img.getWidth();
int height = img.getHeight();
```

it gives me this error:
img cannot be resolved

Could anyone tell me what I did wrong pls

Comment: DO you know what are scopes of variables?

Comment: Java Language Specification [6.3. Scope of a Declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3-520): "*... The scope of a local variable declared in a block ... is the rest of the block, ...*"

Comment: If `ImageIO.read()` fails with an `IOException`, then `img` will not be assigned to. What had you expected to happen in the `finally` block in this case?

Comment: Also `String imgpath = "target.png";` will do nothing as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot I don't have a lot of experience with Java lol.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is "img" is only defined in the inner "try" block. Try this:

```
Image img = null;
try {
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("target.png"));
        String imgpath = "target.png";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} finally {
    if (img != null) {
        int width = img.getWidth();
        int height = img.getHeight();
    }
}
```